# React Native iOS build fails - Mac M1

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I created a react-native project and added Firebase libraries to it. After which when i try `npx react-native run-ios` the build fails with below message.

```
CompileSwift normal x86_64 (in target 'ExpoModulesCore' from project 'Pods')
        CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler (in target 'ExpoModulesCore' from project 'Pods')
```

I tried `pod clean and pod install, pod deintegrate` etc. Cleaned the xcode `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` Nothing works, my `React Native version 0.64.3`

Restarted my laptop as well :)

Comment: Did you manage to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add **arm64** architecture to debug mode.

```js
Targets -> Build Settings -> Excluded Architectures -> Any IOS Simulator SDK
```

Answer (score -1):

After cleaning the project, try the following command and let me know how it goes.

```
arch -x86_64 react-native run-ios
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I still get same error